# Spring Data JPA: Check Exists Entity ID with @Query Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make a simple JPQL using for check exist Entity Id.

**My PlanDetail Entity:**

```
Entity
@Table(name="T_PLAN_DETAIL")
public class PlanDetail extends AbstractProcessEntity {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TERRITORY_ID")
private Territory territory;
...
}
```

I want to check it using Assert:

```
Assert.isTrue(planDetailRepository.existsByTerritory(territoryId), "This territory exist with ID = " + territoryId);
```

**My PlanDetail Entity:**

```
public interface PlanDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<PlanDetail, Long> {

@Query("SELECT COUNT(e)>0 FROM PlanDetail e WHERE e.terrritoryId=?1")
boolean existsByTerritory(Long territoryId);
}
```

Error Log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: terrritoryId of: test.domain.model.plan.PlanDetail [SELECT COUNT(e)>0 FROM test.domain.model.plan.PlanDetail e WHERE e.terrritoryId=?1]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

Any help is appreciated. Can you advise me any JPQL document.. Thanks.

Comment: Hasn't `terrritoryId` too many r?

Comment: Yes I dont have terrritoryId. But I have Territory entitiy, I want to check territory id from Territory Entitiy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Territory entity has a field called "id".

Change your query to:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(e)>0 FROM PlanDetail e WHERE e.territory.id=?1")
```

Comment: I have a simple question, I recently started with JPA and writing queries with query annotation. Are `Query annotation` queries  execute faster than the one with Named queries and writing `findByProperty` ?